# Compactification of compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Let $(Y,h)$ be a compactification of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, prove that $h(X)=Y$.

**My attempt**. Since $(Y,h)$ is a compactification of $X$, we have that $Y$ is a compact space and the function $g: X \to h(X)$ will be a homeomorphism and $h(X)$ is dense in $Y$, then $$\overline{h(X)}=Y.$$
I have to prove that $h(X)=Y$, my idea is to prove that $h(X)$ is closed in $Y$ and we have that $h(X)= \overline{h(X)}$. Since $X$ is compact and Hausdorff we have that $h(X) is also compact and Hausdorff. I have tried to prove that h(X) is closed but I am stuck here. Any suggestions or should I take another way?

Comment: You must include the condition that $Y$ is Hausdorff. For example if $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$ and if the topology on $Y$ is $\{Y,\emptyset,\{0\}\}$ and if $h=id_X,$ then $h(X)\ne Y.$ But $Y$ is not Hausdorff. (This $Y$ is called Sierpinski space. It is useful for many examples and counter-examples.)

Answer (score 1):

Continuous image of a compact space is compact and compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed.